# Use imported variables in jest mock function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I am mocking a function from a file which uses `moment`, Here is the file contents:

./utils/dateUtils:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

export function getToday() {
  return moment().tz(commonTimeZone)
}
```

./containers/someContainer.js:

```
import { getToday } from 'utils/dateUtils'

// Uses getToday in the component
```

./containers/someContainer.spec.js:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

jest.mock('utils/dateUtils', () => {
  return {
    getToday : moment(new Date('2018-01-01'))
  }
})
```

test throws this error:

```
● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/bharat/Documents/redmart-repo/partner-portalv2/app/containers/Orders/PickupsContainer.test.js: babel-plugin-jest-hoist: The module factory of `jest.mock()` is not allowed to reference any out-of-scope variables.
    Invalid variable access: moment
    Whitelisted objects: Array, ArrayBuffer, Boolean, DataView, Date, Error, EvalError, Float32Array, Float64Array, Function, Generator, GeneratorFunction, Infinity, Int16Array, Int32Array, Int8Array, InternalError, Intl, JSON, Map, Math, NaN, Number, Object, Promise, Proxy, RangeError, ReferenceError, Reflect, RegExp, Set, String, Symbol, SyntaxError, TypeError, URIError, Uint16Array, Uint32Array, Uint8Array, Uint8ClampedArray, WeakMap, WeakSet, arguments, expect, jest, require, undefined, DTRACE_NET_SERVER_CONNECTION, DTRACE_NET_STREAM_END, DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_REQUEST, DTRACE_HTTP_SERVER_RESPONSE, DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_REQUEST, DTRACE_HTTP_CLIENT_RESPONSE, global, process, Buffer, clearImmediate, clearInterval, clearTimeout, setImmediate, setInterval, setTimeout, console.
    Note: This is a precaution to guard against uninitialized mock variables. If it is ensured that the mock is required lazily, variable names prefixed with `mock` are permitted.

      at invariant (node_modules/babel-plugin-jest-hoist/build/index.js:12:11)
      at newFn (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/visitors.js:276:21)
      at NodePath._call (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:76:18)
      at NodePath.call (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:48:17)
      at NodePath.visit (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/path/context.js:105:12)
      at TraversalContext.visitQueue (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:150:16)
      at TraversalContext.visitMultiple (node_modules/babel-traverse/lib/context.js:103:17)
```

Not sure what am missing here, does someone know how to fix this error.

P.S. I tried `jest.doMock` but it doesn't mock anything.

Answer (score 11):

Your problem is that `jest.mock` calls are *hoisted*, which means they are put at the very top of the file. It's kind of tricky to find it in the docs, but they say it under [`jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).

That makes your executed code to look something like this:

```js
jest.mock('utils/dateUtils', () => {
  return {
    getToday : moment(new Date('2018-01-01'))
  }
})

import moment from 'moment-timezone'
```

And as you can see `moment` is used before imported, and thus the error message about referencing out-of-scope variables.

There are multiple ways to avoid this.

However, using `jest.doMock` should have avoided the hoisting. I wonder if the path is missing something like `'../utils...` –note the initial `../`–

There's also the fact that you are defining `getToday`'s mock as a value instead of a function, which might have made your tests fail when the module was actually mocked.

Anyways, there are two main ways to mock the module

### [ES6 Class Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks)

The idea is to first mock the import and then define the mocked implementation.

```js
import moment from 'moment-timezone'
import * as dateUtils from 'utils/dateUtils'

jest.mock('utils/dateUtils')

dateUtils.getToday = () => moment(new Date('2018-01-01'))
```

### [Manual Mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks)

Here you create a mock file with the mocked implementation of the module that will be imported wherever you mock the module. That mock file has to live in a `__mocks__` folder which needs to be at the same level of the file you want to mock. For example:

```
├── utils
│   ├── __mocks__
│   │   └── dateUtils.js
│   └── dateUtils.js
│
├── other folders
```

the code would look like this:

```js
// utils/__mocks__/dateUtils.js
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

export const getToday = () => moment(new Date('2018-01-01'))
```

And the tests:

```js
// containers/someContainer.spec.js
import * from './path/to/utils/dateUtils'

jest.mock('./path/to/utils/dateUtils')

// your tests here
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to require the packages locally in a mock, this is to ensure no external variables are used -

```
jest.mock('utils/dateUtils', () => {
  const moment = require("moment-timezone");
  return {
    getToday : moment(new Date('2018-01-01'))
  }
})
```

Here's the link to the relevant issue - https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2567.